# Copy and Paste Solver Results after each run

Tags: excel, solver, vba

I have a sub to run the Solver 50 times using the Solver functions. However, I am trying to copy and paste the Solver results after each run. For example, on the Optimization tab, cell range E1:O13 are showing the solver results but each run the results will be overwritten on the same section. I want to copy the cell range E1:E13 over to another worksheet call "SolverResults" starting from Cell A1, say range Cell A1:K13 for the first run of Solver, and then copy and paste the second run of Solver into cells A16:K28, so on so forth. 
For the copy and pasting part, I don't know how to use a loop, so currently on the SolverResults tab, I only show one section of data on A1:K13, which is when the Solver finishs running 50 times and the F1=221.

Anyone knows how to use a loop to copy and paste the results section by section? I am pretty new to VBA, so any suggestions are appreciated!

```
    {Sub RRS()
For i = 0 To 50 Step 1
SolverReset
Range("F1") = 271 - i
    SolverOk SetCell:="$L$13", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0.01, ByChange:="$F$4:$F$12" _
        , Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverOptions MaxTime:=0, Iterations:=0, Precision:=0.001, Convergence:=0.0001 _
        , StepThru:=False, Scaling:=False, AssumeNonNeg:=True, Derivatives:=2
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$F$4:$F$12", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$I$4:$I$12"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$F$4:$F$12", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="$H$4:$H$12"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$F$13", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="1"
    SolverSolve (True)
    SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1
    Worksheets("Optimization").Range("E1:O13").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("SolverResults").Range("A1")
Next i
End Sub
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
Worksheets("Optimization").Range("E1:O13").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("SolverResults").Range("A1")
```

With this

```
If i = 0 Then

    Worksheets("SolverResults").Range("A1").Resize(13,11).Value = _ 
        Worksheets("Optimization").Range("E1:O13").Value

Else

   Worksheets("SolverResults").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(13,11).Value = _ 
        Worksheets("Optimization").Range("E1:O13").Value

End If
```

Comment: Thank you so much Scott! The code now copy and paste the result section by section now, which is great! I have one more question to you: I just realized the code is copying and pasting the formulas in range E1:E13 from Optimization Sheet over to SolverResults sheet, can I simply just copy the value and format from E1:E13 over to SolverResults after each run of Solver?

Comment: @jcmachine - give the edit a try, you may need to adjust the resize arguments to get it just right

Comment: Thanks a lot Scott! I am trying it out now :-) Your help is highly appreciated :-)

Comment: Hi Scott, the copy and paste with value works great now!! Thank you so much! However, the Slover function cannot loop through with i = 1 and after. For example, on the solver results tab, I have 50 section of results when F1=271, and the code wants the Solver to loop 50 times, where F1=270, 269, 268, etc. It is my first time of using the loop through function doing solver, without the copy and pasting result, I am able to loop through 50 times and eventually F1=221.  Do you know what could cause this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: you're welcome @jcmachine - please mark as answered so others now going forward

Comment: Hi Scott, as per my last comment, I have one last question on the copy and pasting results showing 50 sections of where F1 = 271, instead of Solver looping through 50 times where F1=270,269 and on wards ? Do you know why?

Comment: @jcmachine - did you step through it line-by-line to see what is happening?

Comment: Hi Scott, I tried to comment out the copy and paste codes, the loop through works with i = 0 to 50, if I add the copy and paste codes, it seems the Sover function will only do i=0. Is it possible that the Solver function won't stop and let me copy / paste the result before moving onto next i?

Comment: @jcmachine - the original code worked, correct? where you copy and pasted to A1 everytime ... if that worked, so should my adjustment. ... make sure the `.Value` to `.Value` range size is identical ... i did quick math on it

Comment: Yes, the original code worked. The range size is identical as well. Is it possible that the Solver loop function won't even stop, copy , paste the results and then move onto next i? One of my colleagues told me that I cannot stop the Solver during the loop? Do you think that is possible?

Comment: Hi Scott, I re-arrange the codes, and it worked!! Sorry I don't know how I can insert my codes in the comment so that you can see it as well. :-) But anyway, it worked perfectly now!! Thanks a lot for your help!